# Subsubsection and enumerate combination

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I can't manage to combinate the effects of enumerate and subsubsection in Latex. The output PDF shows a strange error. Here's my code:

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduzione al Cloud Computing}
ahem
\section{Sicurezza dei sistemi Cloud}
hum
\subsection{Principali vulnerabilità della sicurezza in\\ambiente Cloud}
hey
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \subsubsection{Data Breaches}
    hello
        \begin{itemize}
        \item ciao
        \end{itemize}
    \item \subsubsection{Data Loss}
    hi
    \item \subsubsection{Account or Service Traffic Hijacking}
    bzz
    \item \subsubsection{Insecure Interfaces and APIs}
    what
    \item \subsubsection{Denial of Service}
    ohnoes
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and here's the strange result:

[image: Preview]

subsubsection numbers 2 and 3 are overlapping. If I cut the first item's "sub-itemize", that is:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item ciao
\end{itemize}
```

the problem fades away!
What am I missing?
I am using Texmaker, and the following packages: fancyhdr, indentfirst, graphicx, newlfont, amssymb, amsmath, latexsym, amsthm, xcolor, hyperref, breakurl.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can't possibly be correct markup (even if it doesn't generate an error) to use a sectioning command inside a list, lists are intended to be _within_ a section.

Comment: If you want sectioned subsubsections don't do this, just increase the `secnumdepth` counter so they are numbered automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You can number subsections by increasing `secnumdepth` and use just the subsubsection counter not the full 1.1.1 prefix by redefining `\thesubsubsection`. section headings should never be used *within* a list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduzione al Cloud Computing}
ahem
\section{Sicurezza dei sistemi Cloud}
hum
\subsection{Principali vulnerabilità della sicurezza in\\ambiente Cloud}
hey

\subsubsection{Data Breaches}
    hello
        \begin{itemize}
        \item ciao
        \end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Data Loss}
    hi

\subsubsection{Account or Service Traffic Hijacking}
    bzz
\subsubsection{Insecure Interfaces and APIs}
    what
\subsubsection{Denial of Service}
    ohnoes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! This solution works well, too!

Answer (score 4):

A blank line (i.e. a `\par`) after the `itemize` fixes the problem.  However it is not clear to me why you want to use `\subsubsections` here:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduzione al Cloud Computing}
ahem
\section{Sicurezza dei sistemi Cloud}
hum
\subsection{Principali vulnerabilità della sicurezza in\\ambiente Cloud}
hey
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \subsubsection{Data Breaches}
    hello
        \begin{itemize}
        \item ciao
        \end{itemize}

    \item \subsubsection{Data Loss}
    hi
    \item \subsubsection{Account or Service Traffic Hijacking}
    bzz
    \item \subsubsection{Insecure Interfaces and APIs}
    what
    \item \subsubsection{Denial of Service}
    ohnoes
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!
The reason why I want to use the subsubsection, is that, for every item of the enumerate, I have 5-6 pages of text, so I don't want to have a 30-35 pages enumerate in just one chapter. Doing this way, I can mantain the enumeration order, and the template will automatically create "subsubsection bookmarks" for every instance of the list. Thank you again!